# Word meaning both useful and essential

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word meaning a thing that essential and indispensable, but with strong connotations of being functional and useful.  This thing is essential because it is useful.

The closest I've been able to find is *necessity*, but that doesn't seem to highlight the functional nature of the thing in question.  On the other hand, a term like *utilitarian* doesn't imply indispensable.

*Example Sentence:*  Stack Exchange has become **X**, it's hard to imagine living without something so useful.

Comment: To me, *indispensable* has a very strong connotation of utility. I tried in vain to construct a scenario where I would label something useless as *indispensable* (although I believe I could stretch it with *requisite* or *necessary* and make something work).

Comment: Essential connotes properties which make up a thing which are defining. Indispensable connotes properties which are required to fulfill a particular function.

I think the word you want is indispensable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**instrumental** has a connotation of both utility and necessity

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instrumental)

[image]

Comment: This is a good one, I wish I could remember why I needed this word...

Comment: @Chris Sunami ~ haha I only realized after the fact that this question was two years old, oh well it'll help someone who searches it years down the line, and I bet that's an inevitability rather than a possibility, what with it being such a useful question.

Answer (score 2):

I think [fundamental](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paramount) may express the concept that you want to convey regarding the importance of something which has become crucial to the necessities of a community.

> - forming or serving as an essential component of a system or structure; central.

also [paramount](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paramount) may suggest the idea:

> - of the greatest importance or significance; pre-eminent